# Handling the 'Faulted' state of a Workflow

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation-4

I'm wondering how best to handle the Faulted state in a WF4 workflow service host. I'm using a console self-hosted service. I understand one approach is to implement the IErrorHandler interface, but does anybody know how I then configure this on my service? i.e. How do I add to the Behaviors collection?

Additionally, I wonder if anybody had any thoughts/advice on how best to handle a 'restart' scenario (or indeed if it's possible??) once the workflow service host has entered the Faulted state. My understanding is that once the service host enters the faulted state then it is end game and the application is in effect terminated. Can anybody give me a possible strategy for this? I'm thinking maybe a management service on top that handles failed instances of the workflow service host console application - though I'd be interested to hear from people who've faced this dilemma before, before I attempt anything.

EDIT:

Also, I'm working in a clustered environment. When the cluster enters a fail-over state, the workflow appears to lose connectivity with the database for a period of (no more than) one minute. Has anybody dealt with this scenario specifically?

Thanks in advance
Ian

Answer (score 0):

We have a solution with [Microsoft.Activities v1.8.4](http://wf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Microsoft.Activities%20Overview) see [WorkflowService Configuration Based Extensions](http://wf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WorkflowService%20Configuration%20Based%20Extensions) which allows you to add extensions using a service behavior and some config.